# Core keeps dumping when trying to reverse array using a function to swap values of 2 pointers

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, function-declaration

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    /* read integer array */
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *a = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    
    /* reverse the array */
    for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
        exchange(a[i], a[n - i - 1]);
    }

    /* print the array */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

    /* free the memory */
    free(a);

    return;
    
}

/* write a function that takes two pointers of two intergers and then exchanges the values
in those locations */
void exchange(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

This is the code, the function exchange tries to exchange the values of the integers which these two pointers are pointing to.
Keeps dumping the core.

Comment: Your compiler should be giving warnings, no? Did you read them and try to resolve them?

Comment: Firstly, you should be getting an "implicit declaration" warning for the `exchange` function as it is called before it is defined. Move the `exchange` function to be above `main`. Then you'll get "incompatible type" errors because `exchange` takes pointers but you are passing it `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

In this call of the function exchange

```
exchange(a[i], a[n - i - 1]);
```

the both arguments have the type `int` while the function expects arguments of the type `int *`.

You need to call the function like

```
exchange( a + i, a + n - i - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send address values for exchange functions since arguments of it are declared as pointers. Therefore, you need to change this line

```
exchange(a[i], a[n - i - 1]);
```

to this line because as I mentioned it expects addresses.

```
exchange(&a[i], &a[n - i - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A nicer way would be passing the whole array and indexes to swap.

Like this: [`TRY IT ONLINE`](https://godbolt.org/z/xxP51esM6)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void exchange(int **arr, int n1, int n2);

int main() {
    /* read integer array */
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *a = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    
    /* reverse the array */
    for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
        exchange(&a, i, n - i - 1);
    }

    /* print the array */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

    /* free the memory */
    free(a);

    return 0;
    
}

/* write a function that takes two pointers of two intergers and then exchanges the values
in those locations */
void exchange(int **arr, int n1, int n2) {
    int temp = (*arr)[n1];
    (*arr)[n1] = (*arr)[n2];
    (*arr)[n2] = temp;
}
```